# Warning: failed to read path from javaldx

Tags: java, ubuntu-mate

This used to work.

```
lowriter 'macro:///Standard.Module1.OpenFileWithPW("/home/andy/Documents/New_Journal.odt","password")'
```

Now I get this:

```
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414557/warning-failed-to-read-path-from-javaldx

Comment: @Level_Up Thanks. The problem went away.